# how to show datagridview look like it's downloading data from mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

when the data is loading from mysql to datagridview
it's shown in the same time
what i want to do is when the datagridview show five or seven rows it should stop fetching data for 4 to 5 second then should continuous the stop for 5 second again
something like
for showing the user that the datagridview its downloading data from mysql

please someone help me @tim-schmelter

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

```
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()

    ' Define the SQL to grab data from table.

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM dep0 "

    'Connection String

    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=sql2.freemysqlhosting.net;User Id=sql294434;Password=mI1*hrrD9*;Database=sql294434"

    ' Try, Catch, Finally

    Try

        MysqlConn.Open()
        ContactsCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
        ContactsCommand.CommandText = SQL
        ContactsAdapter.SelectCommand = ContactsCommand
        ContactsAdapter.Fill(ContactsData)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ContactsData


    Catch myerror As MySqlException

        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)

    Finally

        MysqlConn.Close()

        MysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Check out my suggestion in your post on the Microsoft vb.net forum, see if it makes sense [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ca54bb4-6bc8-43cc-8bbc-86110b8ee59b/how-to-show-datagridview-look-like-its-downloading-data-from-mysql-load-data-slowly?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: @KarenPayne sorry but your suggestion the not help me to achieve my goal

Comment: Not sure why as the Task.Delay can be set to wait a given period asynchronously rather than Thread.Sleep which halts other methods from working. The end result is a DataTable is populated and becomes the DataSource of a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED with code example.

If you needed to retrieve data this way, you could have the SQL query retrieve only 5 to 7 rows, assign that data as the data source to the DataGridView, then run a loop, with System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) (to tell it to wait for 5 seconds), and each loop have it grab 5 to 7 more rows, and each time assign the new data source to the DataGridView.

Or you could have it retrieve the data on a timer. This would allow the form to be updated more smoothly. Here's a sample of how you could do it.

```
Private WithEvents myTimer As New Timer

Private Sub myTimer_Tick() Handles myTimer.Tick
    Try
        GetData()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error handeling
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetData.Click
    Try
        myTimer.Interval = 5000
        myTimer.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error handeling
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub GetData()
    Dim MysqlConn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim ContactsCommand As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim ContactsAdapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ContactsData As New Data.DataTable
    'Declare Static variables so they retain their values for the next sub call.
    Static TopNumber As Integer = 5
    Static NewRowCount As Integer = 0
    Static OldRowCount As Integer = -1


    Try
        If OldRowCount < NewRowCount Then
            MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=sql2.freemysqlhosting.net;User Id=sql294434;Password=mI1*hrrD9*;Database=sql294434"
            MysqlConn.Open()
            ContactsCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
            ContactsCommand.CommandText = "SELECT TOP " & TopNumber & " * FROM dep0 "
            ContactsAdapter.SelectCommand = ContactsCommand
            ContactsAdapter.Fill(ContactsData)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ContactsData
            OldRowCount = NewRowCount
            NewRowCount = ContactsData.Rows.Count
            'Increment the variable to grab 5 more the next time.
            TopNumber += 5
        Else
            myTimer.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Done!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error handling
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

But I would not advise retrieving and displaying data this way because it will hurt the performance of the program. What you have will lend better performance.

Comment: please i don't know how to do this could write me a code please i need this

Comment: i think you understand what i want to do but i dont know how to execute this
so could you please help me

Comment: I've update my answer. I hope it helps. @MouhcinIuoanid